# Elasticsearch won't start on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 and installed Elastic Search from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/deb.html and now after starting it didn't result any log whether it started or not.Then I entered command `sudo service elasticsearch status`

```
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendo
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-02-20 12:56:37 IST; 2s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 26953 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_D
  Process: 26950 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd
 Main PID: 26953 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 20 12:56:37 saikiran-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Feb 20 12:56:37 saikiran-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Feb 20 12:56:37 saikiran-ubuntu elasticsearch[26953]: Could not find any executa
Feb 20 12:56:37 saikiran-ubuntu systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process 
Feb 20 12:56:37 saikiran-ubuntu systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered 
Feb 20 12:56:37 saikiran-ubuntu systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with r
```

I tried some solutions on stackoverflow including this `sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch/`
 and even tried restarting the service, but nothing worked. Even this fix https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10671 didn't work.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post the full log error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't have java installed/ recognized.
Try this to install Oracle's java:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

test:

```
java -version
```

then run the ES service:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

everything should work now

Comment: Does Elastic Search's fail with OpenJDK?

Comment: @medley56 Elasticsearch works with both Oracle or OpenJDK. The only limitation is that all nodes and clients need to be using the same JVM version. Currently, elastic.co recommends installing Java version 1.8.0_131 or later. (sources: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_java_virtual_machine.html)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-start-elasticsearch-with-ubuntu-16-04/48730/8), try setting

START_DAEMON to true on /etc/default/elasticsearch

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar problem, and in my case I have installed elastic search version 7.5.1 on Ubuntu  and finally installed successfully and running.